# Scrollbar appears on scrollbox, but cannot use it in IE 8

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

http://jsfiddle.net/m7t9b/

```
  <div style="width:625px;height:220px;overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:scroll;z-index:10;">
                <table width="1000" height="114" border="1">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="126"><blockquote>
                          <blockquote>
                            <blockquote>
                              <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://mrsbagerismath.weebly.com/"><img border="0" width="100" height="111" src="images/ahmed.png" alt="Mr. Ahmed" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mr. Ahmed&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ext. 13417<br />
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Room 417/323<br />
                                <a href="mailto:Ahmed@wcskids.net">Ahmed@wcskids.net</a></p>
                            </blockquote>
                          </blockquote>
                        </blockquote></td>
                        <td width="126"><p><img width="100" height="111" src="images/teachers_clip_image002.jpg" alt="Mrs. Bageris " /><br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mrs. Bageris<br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Ext. 13226<br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Room 226<br />
  <a href="mailto:EBageris@wcskids.net">EBageris@wcskids.net</a></p></td>
                        <td width="126"><p><a href="http://dkudra.weebly.com/" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="100" height="111" src="images/cetkovic.png" alt="Ms. Kudra" /></a><br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mr. Cetkovic<br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ext. 13305<br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Room 305<br />
  <a href="mailto:RCetkovic@wcskids.net">RCetkovic@wcskids.net</a></p></td>
                        <td width="126"><p><a href="http://yassowarrenmott.weebly.com/" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="100" height="111" src="images/teachers_clip_image002_0004.jpg" alt="Mrs. Kudra" /></a><br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mrs. Kudra<br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ext. 13225<br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Room 225<br />
  <a href="mailto:Dkudra@wcskids.net">Dkudra@wcskids.net</a></p></td>
                        <td width="126"><p><img width="100" height="111" src="images/teachers_clip_image002_0006.jpg" alt="Mr. Sagman" /><br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mr. Sagman<br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ext. 13420<br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Room 420<br />
  <a href="mailto:SAGMANW@wcskids.net">SAGMANW@wcskids.net</a></p></td>
  <td width="126"><p><img width="100" height="111" src="images/yasso.jpg" alt="Mr. Yasso" /><br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mr. Yasso<br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ext. 13418<br />
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Room 418<br />
  <a href="mailto:Yasso@wcskids.net">SAGMANW@wcskids.net</a></p></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div>
```

Instead of scrolling when I drag the scrollbar, the text below it gets highlighted. How do i fix this in IE 8?

Use the fiddle to see the whole code.

Comment: Off-topic but... you should not need this many &nbsp;'s. I see you're using them to center text; this is not the way to do that! You should do this using CSS's _text-align_ property. Also setting width and height of an element inside an HTML tag should be done with CSS instead. If you visit [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) there are excellent guides on getting you started with all kinds of topics.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your stylesheet,

```
   -ms-overflow:auto;
```

May it will be help you...

Good Luck!